# UIActivityIndicatorView does not spin immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, queue

I'm facing a strange issue about the animation of the UIActivityIndicatorView.

I have a splitViewController where I have a UITableView on the left side, and another one on the right side.

When I enter the application I am doing some operations in background to load datas and each UITableViewCell of the tables will contains a UIActivityIndicatorView.

The operations that have to be executed on the left side are on a queue. The operations to execute on the right side are on a different queue.

The right side operations have major priority respect the operations that have to be executed on the left side.

When the right side queue start, The UIActivityIndicatorView is placed in each UITableViewCell of the table and starts immediately.

When the left side queue start, The UIActivityIndicatorView is placed in each UITableViewCell of the table but does not start the animation immediately. (I have to scroll the table to force the animation).

How can I solve this situation?
How can I animate the UIActivityIndicatorView on the other table without having to scroll the table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of thread you use to run operation in background but if effect to interface (UIActivityIndicatorView in your situation) my recommendation for you is using the following code to Run UI and load operation thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });
});
```